# Использование переменной другого класса

Tags: qt, c++, ооп

Всем привет.

У меня есть два класса

```
//A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include "ui_A.h"

#include "B.h"
#include <QLine>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class A : public QDialog, public Ui::DialogClass
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  A(QWidget* parent = 0);
 ~A();

 bool getValue()
 {
    return _value;
 }

public slots:

private slots:
private:
  B* b;
  bool _value;    
protected:
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};
#endif // A_H

//B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <QtGui>
#include "ui_B.h"
//class Dialog;
class B : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidgetClass//,public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  B(QWidget *parent = 0);
 ~B();
 //B(QObject *parent = 0);
protected:
signals:
public slots:
private:
  A* my1;
};

#endif // B_H

    //B.cpp
    #include <QDebug>
    #include "A.h"

    B::B(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
      setupUi(this);
    }
    B::~B()
    {
    }
    void B::on_button1_clicked()
    {
        //if(my1->getVaue() == true)//Как тут использовать getvalue()??
             //my1->getValue() = false;
       // else
            // my1->getValue() = true;
      update();
    //  qDebug()<<"text";

    }

        //main.cpp
       #include "A.h"

    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QApplication>

    #include "B.h"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        A a;
        //B my1;
        a.show();

        return app.exec();
    }
```

**Вопрос.** Как использовать поле _value из класса A в классе B?

Comment: Хм, надо, кажется, наоборот: если экземпляр `B` хочет иметь доступ к экземпляру `A`, то соответственно в классе `B` должен быть указатель на `A`.

Comment: Ну, это как раз легко исправить.

В `b.h` уберите `#include "A.h"` и добавьте просто `class A;`. А в `b.cpp` как раз наоборот добавьте `#include "A.h"`.

Comment: Никого не смущает запись "class A : : public QDialog, public Ui::DialogClass" и "class B : : public QWidget", и что в конце объявлений нет точки с запятой? Такое не будет компилироваться. Когда создается экземпляр класса B ему в конструктор можно передать указатель на экземпляр класса A, а из методов класса B доступ к атрибутам экземпляра класса A можно получить при вызове QObject::parent() с последующем приведением типа к классу А.

Comment: @marioxxx: вы же забыли в начале `B.h` `class A`:

    #ifndef B_H
    #define B_H

    #include <QtGui>
    #include "ui_B.h"

    class A; // <--- вот это!

    class B : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidgetClass
    {
        Q_OBJECT

Comment: Теперь все собирается, но при нажатии на кнопку программа прекращает работу, т.е. вылетает..

Comment: В void B::on_button1_clicked() указатель my1 не инициализирован.

Comment: Перепробовал так, в B.cpp проинициализировать в начале файла,   т.е. после строки   setupUi(this); 

написать вот так,

my1->_isBeingMouse1=false;

Прога вообще не запускается. В общем не знаю где еще проинициализировать. Внутри функции void B::on_button1_clicked() попробовал там добавить инициализацию, вылазивает при нажатии на button1, APPCRASH. Вот так.

Comment: @marioxxx: не, разве ж это _инициализация_? У вас указатель `my1` равен непонятно чему, а вы его уже разыменовываете. Вы сначала проинициализируйте переменную `my1`, а `my1->_isBeingMouse1=false;` — это _обращение_ к переменной.

Comment: Инициализацию вот так сделал в фале B.cpp

setupUi(this);

my1 = new Dialog(this);

Если запускать программу то зависает.

Плюс еще сделать переменную _value static, т.е. public static _value; 

Ругается, при обращении  bool _s = A._value;

B.cpp:45: ошибка: expected primary-expression before '.' token

Придется по другому варианту делать, создать глобальную переменную, и туда же впихывать значения.

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт!

Answer (score 2):

Вроде как так должно полететь.

// A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QObject>

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    bool _value;
public:
    A(QObject* parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent), _value(true)
    {}

    bool getValue() { return _value; }
    void setValue(bool value) { _value = value; }
};
#endif // A_H
```

// B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <QObject>
#include "A.h"

class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    A* my1;

public:
    B(QObject *parent = 0);
    void on_button1_clicked();
    void printValue();

public slots:
};
#endif // B_H
```

//B.cpp

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include "b.h"

B::B(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent), my1(new A())
{
}

void B::on_button1_clicked()
{
    if(my1->getValue())
        my1->setValue(false);
}

void B::printValue()
{
    qDebug() << "Value is " << my1->getValue();
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "b.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    B b;

    b.on_button1_clicked();
    b.printValue();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Ну понятное дело. Точку с запятой после определения класса в каждом хедере нужно поставить.

Comment: кстати, а у Вас в хедерах у классов стоит макрос Q_OBJECT?

Comment: поправил код. И выложил пример, который нормально компилируется. Метод on_button1_clicked() можешь потом в слот запихнуть. 
printValue() - просто, чтоб увидеть, что все изменилось.

Comment: вот так у меня полностью, посмотрите код..

Comment: А ничего не должен знать о В. Так что все упоминания о классе В, в хедере A.h нужно убрать. 
include "A.h" написать в B.h, а не в B.cpp. 
В main почему Вы используете объекта класса А, если Вам нужен объект класса В? 
Класс В инкапсулирует в себе класс А. Поэтому внешний мир ничего не знает о классе А и работает с ним только через объект класса В.

Comment: мне надо использовать  b.on_button1_clicked() в файле B.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Судя по коду, вы вполне можете объявить класс `A` **другом** (**`friend`**) класса `B` или, ещё лучше, объявить друзьями *отдельные методы* класса `B`, которые пользуют `_value`. Тогда, из *друзей*, вы сможете получить доступ к закрытым членам класса `A`.

При этом, **реализация будет по прежнему *скрыта* от всех других классов** и сущностей.

Для этого в объявлении класса `A` просто добавьте необходимые директивы `friend`. Вот например, как объявить метод дружественным.

```
class A {
    friend void B::changeValue();

    private:
        int _value;
};

class B {
    void changeValue() 
    {
        a->_value = 2;
    }

    private:
        A *a;
};
```

Comment: ругается на
В строке private A *a; 

"b.h:38: ошибка: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'A' with no type" и "b.h:38: ошибка: expected ';' before '*' token" в строке private A *a;

В строке friend B::on_button1_clicked(); "A.h:17: ошибка: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'on_button1_clicked' with no type"

"A.h:17: ошибка: prototype for 'int B::on_button1_clicked()' does not match any in class 'B'

"B.h:31: ошибка: candidate is: void B::on_button1_clicked()"

Comment: @marioxxx, похоже, вам необходимо указать тип возвращаемого методом значения при объявлении `friend`.

    friend void B::on_button1_clicked();

Comment: теперь ругается на строку

private A* a;
 
"b.h:38: ошибка: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'A' with no type" и "b.h:38: ошибка: expected ';' before '*' token".

Если что, в B.h прописан #include "A.h". В A.h написан #include "B.h".

Comment: @marioxxx, может, за вас ещё и код написать?

Скорей всего, название конструктора класса `A` не совпадает с названием самого класса.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку ответить.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем, за ответы и за советы, всем +1!) 
Для решения данного вопроса, использованы части ответов от участников, за это им большое спасибо.) Еще добавлена инициализация.

```
    //A.h
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include "ui_A.h"
    #include "B.h"
    class A {
    private slots:

     friend void B::on_button1_clicked();
        private:
            int _value;
    };

    //B.h
    #ifndef B_H
    #define B_H

    #include <QtGui>
    #include "ui_B.h"
    class A;
    class B : public QWidget, public Ui::MyWidgetClass
    {
      Q_OBJECT

    public:
      B(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~B();

    protected:
    signals:
    public slots:
     void on_button1_clicked();
    private:
      A* my1;
    };

    #endif // B_H

    //B.cpp
    #include <QDebug>
    #include "A.h"
    #include "B.h"
    B::B(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),my1((A*)parent)
    setupUi(this);
    }
    B::~B()
    {
    }
    void B::on_button1_clicked()
    {
            if(my1->_value == true)
                 my1->_value = false;
            else
                 my1->_value = true;
      update();
    }

    //main.cpp
    #include "A.h"
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);

      A a;
      a.show();

      return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Можно еще добавить

в файле A.h

friend class B;

и в файле B.cpp

my1->_value=false;

чтобы в начале было значение false.